# Probability of Choosing a Unique Sensor of Specific Type During Sampling

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given total number of Sensors in a region = **S=100**. Each sensor has a unique ID due to its unique location in the region of interest and also has a specific category **T** due to kind of measurement it takes. We have 5 categories as, 10% sensors belong to T1, 20% to T2,  50% to T3,  10% to T4 and 10% to T5. We have 10 sampling intervals, we randomly choose a sample of 4 sensors at each interval. In the sample the sensors must have unique ID but could be of any category. (For Example : All could be of same category or all could be of different categories or mixed). In the next sampling interval, the same holds and we can have a repetition of the sensor having a unique ID. We represent each sensor as ID(#)T(#). For example we could have the samples as:

Sampling Interval 1: SAMPLE= {ID(45)T(5), ID(33)T(4), ID(10)T(4), ID(1)T(4)}

Sampling Interval 2: SAMPLE= {ID(88)T(1), ID(45)T(5), ID(99)T(3), ID(1)T(4)}

**Question No 1:**

1). Given the aforesaid scenario, what is the probability at each **sampling interval** that a sensor with a specific ID is likely to be part of the sample of **4** picked from total of **100** ?

**Question No 2:**

2). Given the aforesaid scenario, what is the probability at each **sampling interval** that a sensor with a specific type is likely to be part of the sample of **4** picked from total of **100**?

**Question No 3:**

3. Given the aforesaid scenario, what is the probability at each **sampling interval** that a sensor with a specific type and ID is likely to be part of the sample of **4** picked from total of **100**

I need help in my scenario against the combinatorics and probability assessment expressions.

Comment: Where are you having troubles? Is it the fact that you are given more information than you need to solve the problem?

Comment: I have edited the requirements and the 3 parts I need generic expressions please.

Answer (score 0):

Probability that the one ID you chose is represented is the same as the compliment of the one ID you chose is not represented:

$$1-\dfrac{\dbinom{99}{4}}{\dbinom{100}{4}} = \dfrac{4}{100} = \dfrac{1}{25}$$

Probability that the one type you chose is represented is the same as the compliment of the one type you chose is not represented. Since there are $10, 20, 50, 10, 10$ of each of types 1,2,3,4,5 respectively, you have:

$$\begin{array}{rr}\text{Type 1, Type 4, Type 5}: & 1-\dfrac{\dbinom{90}{4}}{\dbinom{100}{4}} = \dfrac{8279}{23765} \approx 34.84\% \\ \text{Type 2}: & 1 - \dfrac{\dbinom{80}{4}}{\dbinom{100}{4}} = \dfrac{6077}{10185} \approx 59.67\% \\ \text{Type 3}: & 1-\dfrac{\dbinom{50}{4}}{\dbinom{100}{4}} \approx 94.13\% \end{array}$$

For (3), it depends. Is it possible that whomever is guessing will guess an ID and Type that are mismatched? Like, in your example, they will guess ID(45)T(1), which does not exist since ID(45)T(5) exists? If guesses with type mismatches are not possible, then guessing the ID is the same as guessing the ID + Type. If type mismatches are possible, then what is the probability the guesser guesses a valid ID/type combo?

Comment: Thankyou for the comprehensive answer and for (3), the working done in (1) and (2) cater and suffices. My queries stand addressed.